# Webservices between Java & c# - complex data types

Tags: c#, java, web-services, type-conversion

currently I'm working on exchanging information between a java application and a .net application using webservices.
All the primary data types (double, int, string, ...) are exchanged correctly.
Also a simple array is correctly transported.

However, I'm trying to transport HashMap's from java to .net (and back, although I know .net doesn't have HashMap's, so I'll probably use Dictionary or some sort). 
Any idea on how to do this?
I know I could just use arrays, but I'd like a better solution if possible.

more specific, it would be something like this:

```
@WebMethod 
public HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>> 
               foo(@WebParam(name = "bar") String path){...}
```

Comment: This may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4654423/how-to-have-a-hashmap-as-webparam-with-jbossws-3-1-2.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the option, I'd recommend to exchange data in JSON format. It has the following advantages

1. Its less verbose compared to xml
2. Easier on network bandwidth  Lesser
3. parsing overhead on the client end.

However if your map object has circular references, then you may have to jump thru hoops. Take a look at [Jackson library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) for conversion to JSON